# jQuery: hide/show don't respect maxHeight/maxWidth options

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a dialog, and within that dialog are some checkboxes. When the checkboxes are selected, they expand showing more content using show(). I have the dialog's height option set to 'auto' and maxHeight set to 900. Problem is, when you click on the check boxes, the dialog grows larger than it's max height.

```
$("#some-id").dialog({
   height: 'auto',
   maxHeight: 900
});
```

I cannot set height to an explicit value because I don't know how big it is going to be initially.

Why is it that hide()/show() violate the maxHeight and how can I fix it?

Comment: From the description of the maxHeight option, I think it only pertains to if the dialog is resizable by the user. You will probably have to use css to set max-height on an element in the dialog that contains your content.

Comment: You are exactly right. Make that an answer and it will be accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the description of the maxHeight option, I think it only pertains to if the dialog is resizable by the user. You will probably have to use css to set max-height on an element in the dialog that contains your content.